# How can I find $c$ such that $c(X_1-X_2)/ \sqrt{X_3^2 +X_4^2 + X_5^2}$ forms a t distribution?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, t-distribution

Let $X_1,\cdots,X_5$ be iid random variables from $N(0,\sigma^2)$. Find $c$ such that $c(X_1-X_2)/ \sqrt{X_3^2 +X_4^2 + X_5^2}$ forms a t distribution.

My work:

A distribution $W$ is a t distribution iff $W=U/\sqrt{V/p}$, where $U\sim N(0,1)$ and $V \sim \mathcal{X}^2_p$ with $p$ being the degrees of freedom.

$(X_1-X_2)/\sqrt{2\sigma^2} \sim N(0,1)$, which partially takes care of the numerator in $c(X_1-X_2)/ \sqrt{X_3^2 +X_4^2 + X_5^2}$.

Note that $(X_i - 0)^2 / \sqrt{\sigma^2} \sim \mathcal{X}^2_1$ for $i=1,2,3,4,5$. Since $X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_5$ are independent, then $X_1^2,X_2^2,\cdots,X_5^2$ are, too. A linear combination of chi-squared distributions is also a chi-squared distribution:

$(X_3^2+X_4^2+X_5^2)/(\sigma^2) \sim \mathcal{X}_3^2$

So, we have

$\frac{(X_1-X_2)/\sqrt{2\sigma^2}}{\sqrt{(X_3^2+X_4^2+X_5^2)/(3\cdot\sigma^2)}} \sim t_3$

(Note that the $3$ in the denominator is the degree of freedom for the $\mathcal{X}_3^2$ distribution.)

After some algebraic manipulation, you will get that $c=1/\sigma^2 \cdot \sqrt{3/2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A distribution $W$ is a t distribution iff $W=U/\sqrt{V/p}$, where $U\sim N(0,1)$ and $V \sim \mathcal{X}^2_p$ with $p$ being the degrees of freedom.

$(X_1-X_2)/\sqrt{2\sigma^2} \sim N(0,1)$, which partially takes care of the numerator in $c(X_1-X_2)/ \sqrt{X_3^2 +X_4^2 + X_5^2}$.

Note that $(X_i - 0)^2 / \sqrt{\sigma^2} \sim \mathcal{X}^2_1$ for $i=1,2,3,4,5$. Since $X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_5$ are independent, then $X_1^2,X_2^2,\cdots,X_5^2$ are, too. A linear combination of chi-squared distributions is also a chi-squared distribution:

$(X_3^2+X_4^2+X_5^2)/(\sigma^2) \sim \mathcal{X}_3^2$

So, we have

$\frac{(X_1-X_2)/\sqrt{2\sigma^2}}{\sqrt{(X_3^2+X_4^2+X_5^2)/(3\cdot\sigma^2)}} \sim t_3$

(Note that the $3$ in the denominator is the degree of freedom for the $\mathcal{X}_3^2$ distribution.)

After some algebraic manipulation, you will get that $c=\sqrt{3/2}$

Comment: Are you sure about the $\sigma^2$ term on $c$ there?

Comment: Oh, it should be in the denominator, right? Let me fix that.

Comment: Check a little more carefully.

Comment: The expression in question clearly is invariant under a change of scale and therefore cannot depend on $|\sigma|$ in any way.  That insight might help you check your work and identify where the mistake occurs.  It also shows why if there is any correct answer, there must be *two* of them.

Comment: If you have any doubt, shouldn't this work be included in your question?

Comment: @Glen_b I am not following where I messed up. I moved my work to my question and will delete this answer.

Comment: Consider whuber's statement. And then pay careful attention to your handling of $\sigma^2$ terms. Justify every step.

Comment: @whuber thank you for your comment. I realize now that $c=\sqrt{3/2}$